# Symfony2 FOSUserBundle Registration Role Exception

Tags: php, symfony

i am quite new in Symfony2, i`ve tried to use FOSUserBundle, most of it works fine, but when i try to register i do always get same result:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/own/envelope/vendor/bundles/FOS/UserBundle/Model/User.php line 372
500 Internal Server Error - ErrorException
```

And in Stack Trace i can see that this is caused the empty array with Roles, but i really do have no idea where i can find it or what i should add to configs or somewhere else.

I didn`t override any controlers, only template for registration, but i think i use proper one.

Thanks for answers.

Comment: Where can we find your code? Have you tried with a step debugger to learn where the value is coming from?

Comment: Did you implement a constructor method in your concrete user class and forget to call `parent::__construct()`?

Comment: Hmm, the code is only pure symfony with implemented FOSUserBundle so it`s nothing to show really. And i did not implement `parent::__construct()`

Answer (score 1):

I deleted the method getGroups and addGroups from my custom User Class and it solved the problem.

Comment: I don`t think it solves problem. You need those methods to use properly groups right?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i did found what is a problem - i didn't add any `Role` for `Group`. So in `FOSUserBundle` each `Group` has to have a `Role`, that`s it.

Comment: Which part exactly You don`t understand?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if my problem was exactly the same but atleast it was similar. The error message was the same. After searching for hours I finally understood what went wrong and looking back it has actually been an obvious mistake.

The only thing I had to do was add the following line to the __constructor function of the user class:

```
$this->groups = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
```

It may not have been the OPers solution but maybe it can help someone else!

Answer (score 1):

i got exactly same error but i solved this by constructor overloading of user class

```
 public function __construct(){    
     $this->groups = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
     return parent::__construct();
 }
```